# jax rs jersey @singleton not working

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

Hi I am a newbie and trying jax rs with jersey.

```
 @Path("test")
 @Singleton 
 public class MyResource {

  private int count;
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String testMethod(){
    count  = count + 1;
    System.out.println("count is" + count);
    return "the count is  called " + count +" times";
   }
  }
```

Here the count variable is supposed to return updated count value for each new request because MyResource class is singleton. But it simply return the same value 1 always. Why its so and how to solve this.

Comment: Are you using `javax.inject.Singleton`?

Comment: thanks... that's it... I was just using import com.google.inject.Singleton;